# Data size of table by column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to return the size of data for a single column in a SQL server 2008 table. I know that:

```
sp_spaceused 'mySchema.myTable'
```

will give me the data size of the total table but is there any way of returning data size for a single column within the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There really isn't a concept of "space used for a column", because the data is stored by records not by columns.  In fact, if you delete a column, you may not recover the space.

You can get the space on the page occupied by the values of columns by using `datalength()` (documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173486.aspx)).

You can get the value for a table by doing:

```
select sum(data_length(col))
from table t;
```

Note that this does not include auxiliary storage for things like `NULL` flags and indexes.

Comment: you touch on the fact storage is actually allocated "by the page", as we can infer, "its more complicated than that." For instance, BIT columns are amalgamated in storage.